# jq sum and multiply values to get an aggregate

Tags: json, jq, inner-product

Given the following JSON, is there a way to get the aggregated memory (sum of all memory values multiplied by the number of instances in each case) with a `jq` query?

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "memory": 512,
      "instances": 3
    },
    {
      "memory": 256,
      "instances": 1
    },
    {
      "memory": 128,
      "instances": 6
    },
    {
      "memory": 1024,
      "instances": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

In this example it should perform the following operation:

```
512*3 + 256*1 + 128*6 + 1024*2
```

so it should give me `4608` in total.

Just for the record, I am using command line `jq` in CentOS8:

```
jq --version
jq-1.5
```

Comment: Your Q will probably continue to garner "close" votes unless you show the jq program you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-liner solution:

```
reduce .apps[] as $x (0; . + ($x | .memory * .instances))
```

Or more elegantly:

```
def sigma(s): reduce s as $x (0; . + $x);

sigma(.apps[] | .memory * .instances)
```